# Find the coin change (Greedy Algorithm) when coins are in decimals and returned amount in coins is larger then original return value

Tags: php, algorithm, sorting, coin-change

I need to find the number of coins that make a given value where coins are in decimals and there is a possibility that the algorithm will return more coins (money) because there is no way to return the exact value where the returned amount is close to the given value.

For example:

```
Coins: [23, 29.90, 34.50]

Value: 100
```

Possible solutions:

```
Solution 1: 34.60, 34.50, 29.90, 23 (122)
Solution 2: 29.90, 29.90, 29.90 ,29.90 (119.90)
Solution 3: 23, 23, 23, 23, 23 (115)
Solution 4: 23, 23, 23, 34.50 (103.5)
```

Based on the possible solutions, the clear winner is "Solution 4" and I am looking for an algorithm that will help me to solve this issue. I don't care how many coins are used I just need to be sure that returned values in coins are as close as passed/desired value.

Does someone know the solution or algorithm for this case?

Comment: Firstly, I wonder if you have problems with defining an algorithm or with implementing it in PHP. Further, you mention that "coins are in decimals" (meaning they have fractional values, I guess), but that seems to be irrelevant, because you can always compute using cents.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I have a problem with the algorithm. Yeah, I can always use cents but I wanted to give you a real case scenario. I mentioned PHP because I code in it and PHP can have some limitations from other languages. That's why I mention it.

Comment: Forget about PHP, algorithms are inherently language-agnostic. ;)

Comment: Are you limited by greedy algorithm usage?

Comment: One doesn't need an algorithm to determine that there is no solution... besides, there is no PHP code involved. And if these were values represented as coins, there would have to be denominations - and the algorithm would have to tell which coins to return as change, in the largest denominations.

Comment: @MBo I am not. I just need to find a solution that is closed to the passed value.

Comment: Actually the best winner is `34.5, 34.5, 34.5` since that is the minimal number of coins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Greedy algorithm assumes that you get the largest possible coin, then the next possible and so on until you reach the sum. But it does not provide the best solution in general case.

So consider using of table containing possible sums:

Multiply sum and all nominals by 100 to work in integers.

Make array `A[]` of length `1 + sum + largest_coin`, filled with zeros, set `A[0]` into `-1`.

For every coin nominal `C` walk through array. If `A[i-C]` is not zero, put value `C` into `A[i]`

After all scan array range `A[sum]..A[max]` to find the first non-zero item. It's index `K` represents the best sum. This cell contains the last coin added - so you can unwind the whole combination, walking down until index 0: `A[k] => A[k - A[k]]` an so on

Python code

```
def makesum(lst, summ):
    mx = max(lst)
    A = [-1] + [0]*(mx+summ)
    for c in lst:
        for i in range(c, summ + c + 1):
            if A[i - c]:
                A[i] = c
    print(A)

    #look for the smallest possible combination >= summ
    for k in range(summ, summ + mx + 1):
        if A[k]:
            break
    if (k == summ + mx + 1):
        return
    # unwind combination of used coins
    while (k > 0):
        print(A[k])
        k = k - A[k]

makesum([7, 13, 21], 30)
```

Array for reference. Non-zero entries - for possible sums.

```
[-1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 13, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 13, 21, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 13, 13, 21, 0, 0, 0, 0, 13, 21, 21, 0, 0, 0, 13, 13, 21, 21, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 21, 21, 21, 0, 0]
```

Combination:

```
13
13
7
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment @MBo. Could you please elaborate this part:

__For every coin nominal C walk through array. If A[i-C] is not zero, put value C into A[i]__


I am not 100% sure what to put there.

Comment: I hope you can read Python as pseudocode, I added working Python code for reference

Comment: Perfect! Thank you for python code. It helped a lot.

Comment: This answer is not helpful to researchers who are seeking PHP content.  Not everyone knows Python.  Also, contributors probably shouldn't be earning language tag points while not actually providing an answer in the specified language.

Comment: FYI I've added a PHP version of this answer.

Comment: @mickmackusa Note author looked for **algorithm** to solve the problem, and I gave definitive textual description, then added illustrative code to dispel doubts. "earning language tag points" is inevitable collateral evil :-(

Answer (score 1):

For those searching for a PHP solution, here is a version of @MBo answer:

```php
function make_change($coins, $change) {
    sort($coins);
    $largest_coin = end($coins);
    $sums = [-1] + array_fill(1, $change + $largest_coin - 1, 0);
    
    // fill sums array with coin combinations
    foreach ($coins as $coin) {
        for ($sum = $coin; $sum < $change + $coin; $sum++) {
            if($sums[$sum - $coin]) $sums[$sum] = $coin;
        }
    }
    
    // find smallest combination >= $change
    for ($k = $change; $k < $change + $largest_coin; $k++) {
        if ($sums[$k]) break;
    }
    if ($k == $change + $largest_coin) return [];
    
    // work back through list to get individual coins
    $result = [];
    while ($k > 0) {
        $result[] = $sums[$k];
        $k -= $sums[$k];
    }
    
    return $result;
}

print_r(make_change([13, 7, 21], 30));

// OP question data - converted to integers
print_r(make_change([230, 299, 345], 1000));
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 13
    [1] => 13
    [2] => 7
)
Array
(
    [0] => 345
    [1] => 345
    [2] => 345
)
```

Demo on [3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/ej3Q5)

Answer (score 0):

**Getting started**
I do not have enough reputation to ask in comments I wanted to ask you further questions but here it goes.I believe this can get you started

-Assuming we are not sure how many coins a user is going to pick
-Any of the coins can be the same amount as the others but have to be treated as different inputs
-Any number of coins can be added together so that the sum closest to the desired max can be accepted

**What exactly is the script intended to achieve**

A user picks random number of coins which are recorded then put into array.Any random number of coins can be picked and added and if the sum gets closer to a specific threshold those coins are accepted

**Concept**

```
<?php

$arrX = array("1.1","20.1","3.5","4","5.7","6.8","7.3","8.6","9","10"); //random coins from user
$minthresh = "30";
$desired = "33";
$maxthresh = "35"; //A threshold is necessary if the desired amount is not enforced 



$randIndex = array_rand($arrX, 2); //Pick any random two coins avoid the same coin twice

$sumofpair = $arrX[$randIndex[0]] + $arrX[$randIndex[1]]." Possible acceptable sum<br>"; //Debug to see which two 

coins are picked and how much they give

print_r($randIndex[0]);
echo " pair with ";
print_r($randIndex[1]);
echo " = ".$sumofpair; //Debug to see which two coins are picked and how much they give

if (($sumofpair >= "30") && ($sumofpair <= "35")){ //Check if the sum is within the threshold

echo "<br>found something<br>";

echo "<br>This ".$arrX[$randIndex[0]]."+".$arrX[$randIndex[1]]." Gets you this ".$sumofpair." Which is very close to  

".$desired;


//if a pair is found show which pair exactly and how much did the pair make


} else { echo "<br>No match so far.Refresh again</br>"; //If the pair do not match refresh until a pair is found...See 

below for more info on this }

?>
```

If you were to solve the need for refresh.You will run this in a loop until the pair that gives you the desired is found

You can expand this to check for 3 random and 4 random and so on.

```
randIndex = array_rand($arrX, 3)...randIndex = array_rand($arrX, 4)....
```

Php.net does not say array_rand function cannot pick the same keys.Personally never seen two picked at the same time.If that does happen.
The code should be expanded to record coins that are already picked,which should also prevent adding a coin against itself.

Here is a clean code...run this any sum that return amount between 29 and 35 should return found.

```
<?php

$arrX = array("1.1","20.1","3.5","4","5.7","6.8","7.3","8.6","9","10");
$desired = "32";
$randIndex = array_rand($arrX, 2);

$sumofpair = $arrX[$randIndex[0]] + $arrX[$randIndex[1]];

echo $arrX[$randIndex[0]];
echo " pair with ";
echo $arrX[$randIndex[1]];
echo " = ".$sumofpair;


if (($sumofpair >= "30") && ($sumofpair <= "35")){ 

echo "<br>This coin ".$arrX[$randIndex[0]]."+ This coin ".$arrX[$randIndex[1]]." = ".$sumofpair." This amount ~ equal 

to ".$desired;


} else { echo "<br>Not a match so far.Refresh again</br>"; }

?>
```